# What is the proper tools and technics to analyze a core dump file in Linux

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, coredump

I'm not asking how to find the cause of the crash. Actually there is no crash at all. I can't exclude the possibility of memory leaking but the executable passed Valgrind analysis in the stress testing. However, when it's running in the cloud, with much load, it gradually consumed much memory. Devop had to use kill -6 pid to kill the process and generated a core dump file, then restarted it. With that core dump, what are the good tools and technics to help you locate which part of the code contributed to the very high memory consumption? Thanks!

Comment: What programming languages were used for your executable?

Comment: It's c++ mostly.

Comment: You should try https://github.com/vmware/chap which is free open source software that does what you want.  Documentation is available in https://github.com/vmware/chap/blob/master/USERGUIDE.md and if you get stuck you can ask questions here.

Comment: You should first try the following and post the output to this question:

Comment: "count writable", "count used", "count leaked", "count free", "count stacks" then perhaps "redirect on" followed by "summarize free".

Comment: Cool! Will git it a shot.

Comment: @Tim Boddy Can Chap tell me which part of my code caused high memory consumption?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240936/discussion-between-tim-boddy-and-wqh).